Book about an alien race named the "Xerox" or "Xerx"
A military spaceship was traveling the cosmos, looking for something — either a new planet or other forms of life — and discovered a brutal race of aliens that they were involved in a war with. They captured a female alien and one of the space crew was tasked with taking care of it or something. Somehow, they bonded and the ship went through an asteroid field or something, but it was damaged, and they were one of the few survivors on the ship. To shorten this, they went through challenges and stuff and I forgot how it ends.

"To shorten this". Please don't shorten anything. Tell us every tiny detail that you can remember, even down to any specific words or phrases that you recall.

"Stranded on a hostile planet, Xera, realizing that her only hope for survival is the warlike Scorpio, sworn enemies of her people, approaches their handsome leader and discovers a noble commander who sets her body on fire with his touch." - https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3931196-no-words-alone. This looks kinda porny, but the basic plot points seem to match

Have not read any of them so don't know if there is a plot match but the name made me think of Stephen Baxter's Xeelee sequence.
